# android avd never loads

Tags: android, device, android-virtual-device

I just started Android Development and the Android Virtual Device never finishes loading past the shiny android word. I have a Mac Book Pro with 16 gigs of RAM and an SSD. I'm utilizing Eclipse and have tried running the emulator from both the project and manually.
Any suggestions on how to get the android emulator to load faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wait longer, but only once. I had to set check-mark snapshot in the Android Virtual Device manager and from now on it starts up right away.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put lesser RAM and internal storage for the emulator. And mark the checkbox "Use Host GPU".

Comment: I finally got it to load, but if I check-mark "Use Host GPU" I can't take snapshots, which is useful, so you don't have sit there and reload the emulator.